# Count values of each row in pandas dataframe only for consecutive numbers

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I got a pandas dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

I want to count how many rows are for each id and print the result. The problem is I want to count that ONLY for consecutive numbers in "frame num".

For example: if frame num is: [1,2,3,45,47,122,123,124,125] and id is [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] it should print: 3 1 1 4 (and do that for EACH id).

Is there any way to do that? I got crazy trying to figure it out! To count rows for each id should be enought to use a GROUP BY. But with this new condition its difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) for finding consecutive numbers then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for creating a list of counting consecutive.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
from itertools import groupby

# Example input dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'num' : [1,2,3,45,47,122,123,124,125,1,2,3,45,47,122,123,124,125], 
    'id' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
})

df['s'] = (df['num']-1 == df['num'].shift()) | (df['num']+1 == df['num'].shift(-1))

res = df.groupby('id')['s'].apply(lambda g: list(chain.from_iterable([[len(list(group))] if key else [1]*len(list(group))
                                                                      for key, group in groupby( g )])))

print(res)
```

Output:

```
id
1    [3, 1, 1, 4]
2    [3, 1, 1, 4]
Name: s, dtype: object
```

**Update:** Get the output as a dataframe:

```
>>> res.to_frame().explode('s').reset_index()

   id  s
0   1  3
1   1  1
2   1  1
3   1  4
4   2  3
5   2  1
6   2  1
7   2  4
```

Comment: Wow!! Your answer was really useful!! It works but I have a quick question: is there any way to change the output type? For example in your case to get a dataframe of two columns: ID and NUMBER      ID  =[1, 1, 1, 1,2,2,2,2] and NUMBER=[3, 1, 1, 4,3,1,1,4]. I was wondering this because is the easiest way to manipulate then this data. Again: THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks, I think for some reason Python is not understanding the dataframe as a two-column dataframe when using this "res.to_frame().explode('s')".                   I tried to use this: res.reset_index() which is usually the solution to this problem but somehow it brings the list back. Is the same thing happening to you?

Comment: @JN1997, I can't understand what you say, can you give an example of what your output look like?

Comment: Sure. In your example: "res" is not a two column-dataframe, right? It has only one column. Is there any way to change it to  a two-column data frame? It seems to have two columns but when you ask Python, it says that is has only one column.

Comment: @JN1997, `res.reset_index()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249407/discussion-between-jn1997-and-imahdi).